# Averages of 4 numbers excluding 0s

Tags: excel-formula

I have 4 numbers I need to add up from a database example (12, 0, 0, 3) I need to know the average of these numbers ignoring the 0s as in 12 + 3 /2 = 15 Ave 7.5. I cannot find a way of avoiding the 0s which makes the answer 12 + 3 /4 = 3.75.

Thanks For Any Help

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=AVERAGEIF(A1:A3,">0",A1:A3)
```

works with your numbers... 12 in A1, 0 in A2, 3 in A3.